# Integral of a real-valued function with complex solutions

Tags: complex-analysis, indefinite-integrals, complex-integration

Basically, I've been banging my head for ages about this integral
$$\int \frac{x^2}{\cos(x) + \sin(x)}\,dx$$

I've tried to simplify it to$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt2} \int x^2\sec(x-(\pi/4))\,dx$$
But that's when it got especially difficult.

Any ideas on how to solve it without using the WRA?

Comment: The solution of this integral is not elementary $$\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right) \sqrt[4]{-1}
   \left(2 x \text{Li}_2\left(-\sqrt[4]{-1} e^{i
   x}\right)-i \left(-2 i x
   \text{Li}_2\left(\sqrt[4]{-1} e^{i x}\right)-2
   \text{Li}_3\left(-\sqrt[4]{-1} e^{i x}\right)+2
   \text{Li}_3\left(\sqrt[4]{-1} e^{i x}\right)+x^2
   \log \left(1-\sqrt[4]{-1} e^{i x}\right)-x^2 \log
   \left(1+\sqrt[4]{-1} e^{i x}\right)\right)\right)+C$$

Comment: What do those 'Li' symbols mean?

Comment: $Li$ is the polylogarithm function